# One Class Classification Models in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, classification

Are there any implementations of One class classifiers in the Spark?

There doesn't appear to be anything in ML or MLlib, but I was hoping that there was an extension developed by someone in the community that would provide some way of producing a trained classification model where only one labeled class is available in the training data.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you were able to implemente one class svm with MLib in the spark, I cannot import the library.

Answer (score 1):

It's Java, not Spark, but [LibSVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) has a one class SVM classifer, and calling it from Spark shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Do you have an example code of how to train SVM as a one-class classification model in pyspark? As far as I have see, there is no parameter to set the SVM to work as a one-class in pyspark. See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.classification.LinearSVC